# Ошибка при вводе - invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python-3.x

```
self.age = int(input("Enter your age:"))
if self.age == "q" :
    break
elif self.age < int(16):
    break
```

Я хочу чтобы при вводе пользователем какого либо слова или буквы выводилось сообщение об ошибке и о том, что нужно вводить число. Но проблема в том, что  выводится данная ошибка:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Как вывести сообщение и как убрать эту ошибку?

Comment: У вас `age` типа int, а в логике сравнивание со строкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Считаем, что весь этот код находится внутри какого-то цикла.

```
self.age = input("Enter your age:")
if self.age == "q" :
    break
else:
    try:
        self.age = int(self.age)
        if self.age < int(16) :
            break
    except ValueError:
        print "error message"
```